# How to send email by using MailKit via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am having difficulty creating the Message object using mailkit so I can add the From, To, Subject and body with message that may have attachments to be send before disconnecting.  I have created the MailKit object, Cancelation Token object.  I am able to load the MailKit and MimeKit dlls using the add-type -path and I am able to connect, authenticate, Disconnect and Dispose but the message object creation part and sending is where I need help with.  I have the following:

```
    $MkSmtp = New-Object MailKit.Net.smtp.SmtpClient
    $CanToken = New-Object System.Threading.CancellationToken ($false)
    $SSL = [MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions]::SslOnConnect
    $MkSmtp.Connect($MailServer, $Port, $SSL, $CanToken)
    $MkSmtp.Authenticate(([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8), $Username, $Password, $CanToken)

    #$Message = New-Object ????

    $MkSmtp.Send($Message)
    $MkSmtp.Disconnect($true)
    $MKSmtp.Dispose()
```

I thought the answer was:

```
    $Message = [Mimekit.MimeMessage]::new()
    $Message.From.Add($From)
    $Message.To.Add($To)
    $Message.Subject = "Test"
    $TextPart = [MimeKit.TextPart]::new("plain")
    $Body = "This is just a test"
    $TextPart.Text = $Body
    $Message.Body = $TextPart
```

Which came from https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSGSuite/2.13.2/Content/Private%5CNew-MimeMessage.ps1.  This worked on my developer machine but putting it to production yields the following error:

> Method invocation failed because [MimeKit.MimeMessage] does not contain a method named 'new'

When it tries to go passed the following line:

```
$Message = [Mimekit.MimeMessage]::new()
```

Placing a breakpoint at this line after loading the dll via add-type and running "[MimeKit.MimeMessage] | Get-Member -Static" on the powershell command line on the development and production server it shows the following:

Development
[image: Development machine showing the New Static Method]

Production
[image: Production server showing no New Static Method]

Same DLL is loaded on both the Development and Production.  I have loaded the DLL using both Add-Type and System.Reflection.Assembly.  Production is on PowerShell 4.0 while my development box is on PowerShell 5.1.  Don't know if that is the issue.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Has noone encountered or seen this type of issue?  Still having difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated our live server to WIndows Management Framework 5.1 (PowerShell) and now has the New Method when viewing the Static Get-Member.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Message = New-Object Mimekit.MimeMessage
```